# Angular 7 & Twilio "A from phone number is required"

Tags: angular, http, twilio

I am trying to use an HTTP request in angular to send a text message using Twilio. I am able to do so in postman using form-data for the body
[postman body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNtmj.png)

however when I try to add form data to an http request in angular, it seems Twilio's api isn't able to read the attribute names properly. All my searching has told me I just need to append them to a formData object and pass that as the second parameter in the post but it doesn't work.

I know my request is reaching the proper endpoint because I was previously receiving a 401 unauthorized response but have fixed that using btoa().

**Here is the code**

```
sendSMS(sendTo: string){

    //actual phone numbers replaced (they worked with postman)

    const to: string = '+15555555555';
    const from: string = '+15555555555';
    const body: string = 'Image Uploaded';

    const username: string = 'username';
    const password: string = 'password';

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('To', btoa(to));
    form.append('From', btoa(from));
    form.append('Body', btoa(body));

    const headers = new Headers({});
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
    headers.append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

    const options = new RequestOptions({headers});

    return this.http.post(this.smsURL,form, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you are trying to make a request to the Twilio API from the client side. The issue here is that you are storing your Twilio credentials in the front-end code which can be read by anyone. This means they could take your credentials and abuse your account.

The recommended way to send an SMS message using Twilio in Angular is to build a server side endpoint that you control that stores the credentials and sends the message. Then you can send the details of the message from your client side to your server, which sends it on with credentials to the API.

I have an [example app that sends SMS messages with Angular and an Express backend](https://github.com/philnash/ng-sms-messages). It uses a [message service to send the details to the server](https://github.com/philnash/ng-sms-messages/blob/master/src/app/message.service.ts) and [this code to send messages from the server](https://github.com/philnash/ng-sms-messages/blob/master/server/routes/index.js#L46-L61).

---

For the record, [when you create a `FormData` object, it makes the request as a `multipart/form-data`](https://philna.sh/blog/2016/06/13/the-surprise-multipart-form-data/). That's why, when you used a string instead it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out

```
sendSMS(sendTo: string){

    const to: string = '+' + sendTo;
    const from: string = '+fromNumber';
    const body: string = 'Image Uploaded';

    const username: string = 'username';
    const password: string = 'password';

    var rbody = `To=+${to}&From=${from}&Body=Image Uploaded`;

    const headers = new Headers({});

    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    const options = new RequestOptions({headers});

    return this.http.post(this.smsURL,rbody, options);


}
```

the trick was to format the body as such:

```
body= 'attribute1=value&attribute2=value2'
```

and set the content type in the header to:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```